# ¿Por qué no puedo excluir columnas vacías en un SELECT de SQL cuando tengo más de 100 columnas sin escribirlas toda?

Tags: sql

Tengo un DB de más de 100 columnas y quiero una tabla que contenga solamente las columnas que no están vacías, ya que en mi tabla de hecho hay columnas vacías.

Pero no puedo hacer un SELECT * FROM table WHERE ___ IS NOT NULL porque tendrías que añadir las más de 100 columnas en el WHERE y eso es muy inneficiente, entonces quería saber si exista alguna manera más sencilla de hacer esto, no es posible no exista un operador que me permita seleccionar todas las columnas en el WHERE para excluir las columnas vacías.

No he investigado mucho pero leí por ahí que se requiere hacer la consulta dinámica y es la primera vez que escucho eso.

Comment: y sabes que columnas no son null? where es para los datos, pero sql es estricto, no muestra o deja de mostrar una columna por ese motivo...

Comment: Creo que andas confundido con términos de DB, tabla, columna y fila. Las bases de datos tienen tablas, las tablas tienen columnas y filas. `WHERE` sirve para limitar las filas que se regresan, no las columnas. Hacer un filtro por 100 columnas, solo indica que tienes un problema de diseño. Hace falta más información para ayudarte.

Comment: De hecho, usar `*` en el `SELECT` es ineficiente.